# Create a Sorted List by Date of Upcoming Payments, from Imported Data of Yearly and Monthly Subscriptions List in Another Sheet Tab

Tags: date, google-sheets, import, google-sheets-formula

**Edit:** Partial solution below. I'm getting closer. I would be super grateful on the last bit.

**Original Post:**
I have a Google Sheet with all of our reoccurring subscriptions and memberships. They are each marked with the price we pay and if they are monthly or yearly reoccurring payments. Something like this:

| Subscription | Subscribed | Monthly/Yearly | Price | Mo. Bill Date | Yr. Bill Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amazon Prime | Yes | Yearly | $139.54 |  | July 2 |
| AMC+ | Yes | Yearly | $88.07 |  | December 5 |
| Gym Membership | Yes | Monthly | $79.00 | 1 |  |
| Netflix | Cancelled | Monthly | $29.52 | 19 |  |
| Peacock | Yes | Monthly | $6.32 | 25 |  |
| Subscription Box | No | N/A |  |  |  |

I'd like to use another sheet tab that creates...

1. A sorted list of upcoming payments in the next 60 days from that data in the other sheet tab.
2. It needs to import data only from active subscriptions.
3. It needs to be based on if it's a monthly or yearly reoccurring payment.
4. It should ignore entries with no $ amount or $0.
5. It should be sorted with the soonest upcoming payment first.

Using data from the above table, it would ideally look something like this:

| Amount Due | Next Payment Date | Subscription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $6.32 | November 25 | Peacock |
| $79.00 | December 1 | Gym Membership |
| $88.07 | December 5 | AMC+ |
| $6.32 | December 25 | Peacock |
| $79.00 | January 1 | Gym Membership |

Sadly, I don't even know where to start and I haven't found anything even close in my searching for somewhere to begin other than basic QUERY imports. The monthly and yearly reoccurring date thing is what seems to be the real killer here, especially since date formatting wants to add a year.

Here's my editable sample sheet with a lot mare data to mess around with:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kHbCNBg17JJ26BLqOAM8UdqRHxjIUtLxAa54mcqlmL0/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be extremely appreciated. Thank you!

**Partial Solution:**
To make things a little easier, I added an extra column to the main Subscription List to determine the 'Next Payment Date' for each Subscription. (That list can then be exported later with QUERY, IMPORTRANGE, and ORDER BY) - *This solution will make it hard for IMPORTRANGE to have more than one payment show for a single subscription for a 60 day outlook though. But one problem at a time I suppose.*

I've been able to figure out how to determine the 'Next Payment Date' for Monthly subscriptions with this...

Column H = 'Mo. Bill date'

`={"Next Payment Date"; ArrayFormula(IF(H2:H<>"",EOMONTH(TODAY()-7,)+H2:H, ))}`

**But** I still can't figure out how to do the same thing for Yearly subscriptions. Google keeps adding a year to the 'Yr. Bill Date' entries for those. But even if that weren't a factor, I can't figure out how to make it behave the same way as the Monthly solution.

Can someone help with this last part? Thank you!

Comment: I added a partial solution but would still really appreciate any help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's [one approach](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kHbCNBg17JJ26BLqOAM8UdqRHxjIUtLxAa54mcqlmL0/edit#gid=1042998109) you may test out:*

```js
=let(Σ,index(reduce(,sequence(match(,0/(A2:A<>""))),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,let(g,index(G2:G,c),a,index(A2:A,c),h,index(H2:H,c),i,index(I2:I,c),if(or(index(B2:B,c)<>"Yes",g=0),,
     hstack(wrapcols(g,3,g),if(len(h),edate(date(year(now()),month(now()),h),sequence(3,1,0)),edate(date(year(now()),month(regexextract(i,join("|",text(edate(0,sequence(12)),"mmmm")))&1),--regexextract(i,"\d+")),sequence(3,1,0,12))),wrapcols(a,3,a)))))))),
     sort(filter(Σ,index(Σ,,2)>=today(),index(Σ,,2)<=today()+60),2,1))
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thank you so much! Does there happen to be a painless way to include the last week of payments by chance? Like an easy "-7" that can be snuck in anywhere? If not, no biggie though. Thank you again!

Comment: Also, if it's not a pain, can you point out the section and explain a little about where the non-date columns are being handled in this formula? (In case I ever want to add content from another column.) Thanks again for everything, I really appreciate it. I'm trying to learn but a lot of what you did here is definitely over my head right now.

Comment: I figured out where to put the -7. Really obvious but got hung up on other code before. I can't believe I didn't realize earlier. Sorry.

Comment: If you get a chance, can you help explain how your solution works a little? Specifically, how and where the non-date columns are being handled. I'm trying to understand it all better and learn a little more. In this case, I'd like to add one or two more columns in the middle, but I can't quite figure it out. Thanks again for everything!

Comment: `let(g,index(G2:G,c)` & `wrapcols(g,3,g)` handles the Column_G *Price* column. `a,index(A2:A,c)` & `wrapcols(a,3,a)` handles the Column_A. These [explanatory videos on reduce/lambda](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLv9Pf9aNgemvXxLZfObnb3cvcG6gerfOB&si=VV7F-XzKr0BK41H4) could be helpful just in case.

Comment: I finally figured out how to add additional columns and those videos are great! Thanks again for everything!